# Haskell - Couldn't match expected type ‘JValue’ with actual type ‘[(String,JValue)]’

Tags: json, haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I have a problem with `JValue`, I previously defined it as:

```
data JValue = 
    JString String
    | JNumber Double
    | JBool Bool
    | JNull 
    | JObject [(String, JValue)]
    | JArray [JValue]
```

And I'm trying to make a function

```
getPosition :: String -> JValue -> Int -> Int
getPosition _ (JObject []) _ = -1
getPosition word (JObject [(name,_)]) index
    | stringsAreEqual word name = index
    | otherwise = -1
getPosition word (x:xs) index = getPosition word xs (index+1)
```

that is intended to find the index of a tuple in a `JObject` that has the same string as the one in the arguments. I'm getting this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘with actual type ‘[(String, JValue)]’
```

What am I doing wrong? I may be complicating myself too much. Thanks

Comment: Aside from your problem I would advise you to use `Maybe Int` as a result type and not use the magic value `-1` for "not-found". Also `JObject (Map String JValue` would be a better choice instead, you get the whole bunch of `Map` functions! And at last your function is partial you need to take account of `JValue`s other than `JObject`, the easiest solution would be using `getPosition _ x _ = error $ "Error: expected JObject in getPosition but got: " ++ show x` which is still a partial function but the error message is better.

Comment: Even if a valid position must be a positive integer, it's better to be explicit about whether you found the string or not by returning a `Maybe Int` instead of an `Int`, in which case you return `Nothing` if the string is not found, and `Just x` if it is found at position `x`.

Comment: Btw. unless you are doing this for learning purposes, use [`aeson`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) instead of writing your own JSON-library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 2nd argument of the last clause, you pattern match against a list `(x:xs)`, but there must be a `JValue`.

When you want to find the index in a list, use `findIndex` from `Data.List`

```
getPosition word (JObject tuples) =
       findIndex (\(name,_) -> name == word) tuples
```